# Discover management IP and use it in a template

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to setup my sshd_config file using Ansible. For design reasons (we have both virtual and physical machines, with different NICs) the management interface is not fixed, so in my template I cannot just put

```
{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
```

because I don't know in advance which interface is going to be management interface so, I need discovering it. I know the IP is always going to be inside a range (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24).

How can I discover which interface has that IP and then use it in the template?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ansible provides a fact named `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` that is a list of all ip addresses.

To find the management IP see this working example:

test.yml:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - set_fact:
        man_ip: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
      when: "item.startswith('192.168.1')"
    - debug: var=man_ip
```

- *set_fact* registers a variable that can be used later in your play
- *with_items* iterates over all ip addresses
- *when: "item.startswith('192.168.1')"* will limit the assignment to ips that start with 192.168.1

Run the test play locally:

```
ansible-playbook -c local -i localhost, test.yml
```

The variable `{{ man_ip }}` will have the ip address of the management ip address.

Comment: should be->      with_items: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"

Comment: Wouldn't that get the OP *all* IPs  for all hosts in their inventory?

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly tricky to run inside a role when you have `gather_facts: false` in your playbook.

However, you can run `setup` selectively inside a role like this.

```
---
- setup:
    gather_subset: [network]

- debug: msg={{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}
```

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html